# Neo4j multiple relationship query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am doing a school project using Neo4j and have run into a problem. I want to get all students that have applied to take exam and taken any exam or registered for, by their ID or indexnumber. I connected students and subjects with exams, which are relationships with properties (STUDENT)-[EXAM]-(SUBJECT) and/or (STUDENT)-[REGISTRATION]-(EXAM). 
I need 1 Student by id, all connections of said student to Subjects in 1 query.
The database looks like this:

```
MERGE (std5:STUDENT { name:'Nola', surname:'Joan', indexnumber:12000, semester:'I' })
MERGE (std4:STUDENT { name:'Pola', surname:'Moan', indexnumber:12001, semester:'II' })

MERGE (sub1:SUBJECT { name:'Databases', semester:'VII' })
MERGE (sub2:SUBJECT { name:'Advanced Databases', semester:'VIII' })

MERGE (std5) - [ :EXAM { signed:' ' , mark:6 , date:'12.01.2017.' }] -> (sub1)//mark 6 is passing
MERGE (std4) - [ :EXAM { signed:' ' , mark:5 , date:'12.01.2017.' }] -> (sub1)

MERGE (std5) - [ :REGISTRATION {date:"2/11/2015", charge:0,  term:'June'}] -> (sub1)

MERGE (std5) - [ :REGISTRATION {date:"2/11/2016", charge:0,  term:'June'}] -> (sub1)

MERGE (std4) - [ :REGISTRATION {date:"2/11/2015", charge:0,  term:'June'}] -> (sub2)
```

The query I used is this one, but gives me double the data and often it is wrong. I need for a specific student to get all exams and registrations for each of those exams, so I may get a complete list of who and when took and or passed exam, registered or if he never did register and took exam.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:STUDENT) - [d:EXAM] - (c:SUBJECT)

WHERE p.indexnumber = 12000  and d.mark<5 //failing grade

WITH collect (distinct c) as c1,d

OPTIONAL MATCH (p:STUDENT) - [b11:EXAM] - (c:SUBJECT)

WHERE p.indexnumber = 12000

WITH p , count(c) as rels, collect(b11) as exams,d,collect(distinct c +c1) as c2

RETURN p, c2, d, rels , exams
```

So to summarize, student is connected either by registration or exam, or both, I need to get all those relationships for said student for index number. Then to count all those relationships to subject, since the data of how many times student took the exam is saved on the relationship exam to said subject. Also all students that have mark <6 failed the exam. So I hold plenty of information and I intend to use it fully in relationships. Multiply this by number of subject and exams, complexity went up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for providing an example dataset. Some suggestions: 1. please add the `cypher` tag to the question so others will find it more easily, 2. your dates in the example are using a mixes syntax 3. what is the condition for failing the exam? The query contains `<5`, but the text suggests `<6`.

Comment: 1. I will look into how to add cypher tag.
2. In our grading system, 6-10 are passing marks, and if someone failed he has his mark set to lower than 6, 5 is if he tried to pass and failed, lower is for no show or something else.
3. Student either failed or didn't, relationship is set beforehand. What I wanted is to get and see for example, which subjects are hardest for said student, which subjects he tried to pass, etc. and have all that data to work with. Also I may see for instance, in reversed query, which of the subjects students find hardest, etc. Hence the need to see all relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand your requirements yet, but a couple of suggestions:

- Use a `MATCH` clause for selecting the student once and reuse that variable later.
- You can shorten your code by including `{indexnumber: 12000}` in the `MATCH` clause instead of adding a condition to `WHERE`.
- Using `collect(distinct c + c1)` includes the `c1` collection for every `c` element, which is probably not what you want.

So, to collect the failed and successful exams, along with the registrations, I'd run a query like this (updated as suggested by InverseFalcon):

```
MATCH (p:STUDENT {indexnumber: 12000})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p) - [e1:EXAM] -> (c1:SUBJECT)
WHERE e1.mark < 5
WITH p, collect(e1) AS failedExams
OPTIONAL MATCH (p) - [e2:EXAM] -> (c2:SUBJECT)
WHERE e2.mark >= 5
WITH p, failedExams, collect(e2) AS successfulExams
OPTIONAL MATCH (p) - [e3:REGISTRATION] -> (c3:SUBJECT)
RETURN failedExams, successfulExams, collect(e3) AS examRegistrations
```

Comment: Given that you're matching all of these before collecting them, you're going to see a ton of duplicates unless you collect their distinct values. Better to collect along the way after each optional match.

Comment: What I wanted to test and use in this project is how to achieve to connect students and subject with relationships, rather than to put a node in between them, instead directly connect them to said subject. I was hoping to get information by collecting number of registrations to exam (how many times student tried to pass the exam), and in those relationships are dates of attempts or no dates if he failed to show on exam, also if passed or failed is in connection exam, where also I can see the date, and in the end which subject, which is node. So I wanted in 1 query to get all this information.